# How make an autocomplete based on 1 input and show information for 2-3 other intput

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I want to create an autocomplete function like this : http://www.codemashups.com/source/jquery/jquery-autocomplete-p1/. You can try yourselft if you want with code : 1000, 1001. 
I already completed my autocomplete. For instance if I enter `Pa` it suggests `Paris`.
Where I need help is here : IF I click on Paris thanks to the suggest in the input 1, I want to complete the State in input 2 : let's say `France`. And in the input 3 `Europe`. Here is my code for in my file autocomplete.php :

```
<html>
   <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#name").autocomplete({
                        source:'getautocomplete.php',
                        minLength:1

                    });
                });
        </script>




        </script>
   </head>

   <body>

      <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
      </form>

      <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" id="client" name="client" />
      </form>

   </body>
<html>
```

And here my code Getautocomplete.php

```
//skip the code to connect for my DB

$con = mysql_connect($host_name,$user_name,$pass_word) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database_name, $con) or die(mysql_error());



 $term=$_GET["term"];
 $query=mysql_query("select * from projets where proNum like '%".$term."%' order by proNum");
 $json=array();

    while($student=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         $json[]=array(
                    'value'=> $student["proNum"],
                    'label'=>$student["proNum"]
                        );
    }

 echo json_encode($json);
```

Any idea ? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem and my solution was, I add more property to autocomplete source, in your case you have to add more properties like state or what ever in php as a follow:

```
while($student=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     $json[]=array(
                'value'=> $student["proNum"],
                'label'=>$student["proNum"],
                'state'=>$student["state"],
                'any_param'=>$student["any_param"]
                    );
}
```

And on the javascript autocomplete select event you can get those properties as follow:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
source: dataSearch,
select: function(event, ui) {
   alert(ui.item.state);//will alert you the state
       console.log(ui.item); //to view all properties of the selected item 
}
 });
```